# Is there a way to optimize freeing of memory allocated for hash table in C?

Tags: c, hashtable

I have a spellchecking program that uses a hash table. I'm trying to optimize it and is there a way to optimize my code for freeing the memory that was allocated for the hash table. I'm trying to make this program as fast as it can go.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 230000;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

bool unload(void)
{
    // loop through the whole hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        while (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = table[i]->next;
            free(table[i]);
            table[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Not really. If you're doing this only when the program is about to exit, you could just skip it -- all the program's memory is destroyed when the process terminates.

Comment: I know but that gives memory leaks, but ok I just wondered If there was faster way to free the memory that was allocated for the hash table anyways thanks for answering.

Comment: You are showing how you free your memory, but not how you allocate it. If you are calling `malloc` 230000 times you can't avoid calling `free` 230000 times, because the addresses could be completely unrelated, so there's no way to make a single, giant free.

Comment: @Unknowsplayer Memory leaks aren't a problem if the program is about to end, since the memory goes away. It's like worrying about leaks in a boat that you're about to retire.

Comment: Instead of using a linked list, use an array, then you can free it all at once.

Comment: Allocate with a unique `node * table = calloc(N, sizeof(*table))` thus you win for the alloc and for the free.

Comment: @Barmar It is hard to manage collisions with an array

Comment: @DavidRanieri Each bucket would be an array. You grow the array using `realloc()` instead of adding list nodes.

Comment: What number are you using for `LENGTH`?

Comment: @Barmar yes, it is possible to do it in this way, but very hard to implement it if the table can grow (rehash)

Comment: @DavidRanieri Rehashing is just as hard with the bucket being a linked list.

Comment: This program should be able to read a txt file that has thousands of words, and loads it into the dictionary using a hash function then we read another file to check for misspelled words if the word read is not found in the hash table then it is considered mispelled, so the goal of this is to create an efficient program for loading the words into the hash table, then for the lookup of words, then free the memory. LENGTH is defined `#define LENGTH 45` as the max number of characters for a word

Comment: @Barmar I don't agree, rehash can be as simple as moving the node from one to the other bucket in a linked list, using your approach means `realloc` both buckets

Comment: @DavidRanieri You're right about that.

Comment: Instead of allocating and freeing each node individually, you can allocate them in large blocks, which you free as a whole. Write a function that creates each node by either returning the next element in the block or allocating a new block.

Comment: With a typical desktop OS, when the program calls `malloc`, and `malloc` doesn't have enough memory, `malloc` will request additional memory from the virtual memory manager (VMM). The VMM typically returns memory in multiples of 4K bytes. Given that a `node` structure is about 70 bytes (with overhead), over 50 nodes will fit into each 4K page that the VMM assigns to the program. At the end of your program, you have two choices: 1) call `free` for every `node`, 2) do nothing and let the VMM clean things up.

Comment: Note that because about 50 nodes fit into a single page, freeing the nodes is at least 50 times slower than letting the VMM free the pages. So although I'm reluctant to make this suggestion, if your primary concern is speed, then you shouldn't free memory at the end of a program. The big risk here is that by ignoring leaks at the end of the program, you'll overlook leaks at other points in the program. So during development, I would be careful to `free` all memory. Only disable the code that frees memory at the end of the program after everything is working perfectly, with no leaks anywhere.